# Bacterial digestion of leaves

Tags: biodegradable-waste

Is it possible to subject plant leaves to bacterial digestion to harness methane production therefrom. Is so what are the limitations.

Comment: Methane is a much more effective greenhouse gas than CO2 so the US EPA considers it harmful and has required refuse dumps with methane collection pipes to seal the pipes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, plant leaves, like pretty much all other organic matter, can be digested by the right bacteria to produce methane, and a nutrient-rich byproduct which can be reused in agriculture as fertiliser.

The standard method is to used [anaerobic digestion](http://www.biogas-info.co.uk/about/feedstocks/) in a closed unit. When done well, this cuts out the risk of fugitive methane emissions, and that's very important, because (as blacksmith37 notes), it's a very potent greenhouse gas.